# Debugging by outputting the full XML of a variable in xslt using xml:message

Tags: java, debugging, variables, xslt, pretty-print

I have a variable called `$statuses`.

I want to output the full XML, rather than just the values in the nodes, so I tried to do the following:-

```
<xsl:message>Contents of the nodeset_statuses:-
    <xsl:copy-of select="$statuses"/>
</xsl:message>
```

However, this only outputs the values in the nodes in the XML which is not what I want. I want the XML "as it is". I've seen some examples of "prettyPrint" templates like with dom4j but I'll be honest it really shouldn't be that much work.

Is there any Java method call available?

I tried something like:

```
<xsl:message>
    <xsl:variable name="output" select="java:System.out.println('print me something')"/>
</xsl:message>
```

With an XML namespace definition of:

```
xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java"
```

But that didn't work as it returned the error:

> System.out.println isn't a recognised part of the java / xslt apache extensions.

Does anyone know what the actual Java call is to achieve what I want or a way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it is not working ?  If you are looking the results through a browser the tags will not display .. except in the source code..

Comment: Positive. I probably should have given context when I posted. I'm testing an application via JBoss so viewing through the server.log in the putty output window any xsl:message output. This is what I get currently...

2010-01-25 18:05:41,865 ERROR [STDERR] file:///jboss-3.2.0/bin/javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource; Line 0; Column 0; Contents of the nodeset_statuses:-
                                    11001223400010334000103The order is already on an ASNthe order is already on an ASN151001223400010301/22/2010 00:00:00 GMT340001031499Automatic rejectionR0201R1308M340C

Comment: So basically I need structure of the xml to understand what the values relate to. I don't currently know what the variable contains as far as XML structure so I can't work out the mappings even if I could comma separate them.

Answer (score 1):

Your comment suggests you're using Xalan, which has an [extension for writing output to different result documents](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensionslib.html#redirect).  Add

```
xmlns:redirect="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/redirect"
extension-element-prefixes="redirect"
```

to the `<xsl:stylesheet>` root element of your transformation, then you can use

```
<redirect:write select="'statuses_debug.xml'">
  <statuses>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$statuses"/>
  </statuses>
</redirect:write>
```

to dump the variable to a separate file (I've added a single root element to make the output well-formed if `$statuses` contains more than one element).

Answer (score 0):

Use the document function and the `xsl:variable` nodeset to read the value:

```
<xsl:message>
  <xsl:value-of select="document('')/*/xsl:variable/@select[../@name='output']"/>
</xsl:message>
```